# how can i set "realm-public-key" in application.properties (keycloak v1.9.8)?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am working on a project which uses version 1.9.8 of keycloak. I would like to know how I can set the public key in my application.properties file.

already try with "keycloak.realm-public-key" and I got

"Failed to bind 'keycloak.realm-public-key' from 'applicationConfig ..."

my application.properties contains the following:

```
keycloak.realm = //the realm name//
keycloak.auth-server-url = //the auth url//
keycloak.resource = //the resource//
keycloak.ssl-required = none
keycloak.realm-public-key = //the key//
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the property is called: keycloak.realm-key. 
The property file would look like this:

```
keycloak.realm = //the realm name//
keycloak.auth-server-url = //the auth url//
keycloak.resource = //the resource//
keycloak.ssl-required = none
keycloak.realm-key = //the key//
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
```